# Can't delete unnecessary provisioning profiles from itunesconnect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have more than 10 provisioning profiles that I do not need, in iTunesConnect.

Having them creates a confusion.

I've tried deleting them several times. However, everytime i hit refresh in xcode the provisioning profiles appear again.

```
How to permanently delete them ?
```

Comment: When you refresh the provisoning profiles, you're asking for them from iTunes connect and they get downloaded again. You should either: >>access the Apple Dev Member Center and delete the profiles from there... or >>once you remove the profiles, don't hit the refresh button any more, since that's not a simple refresh but a full download. (I leave this as a comment since I can't double check this on my computer right now).

Comment: @Injuanj the solution was simply to wait for a few minutes before hitting refresh, and i waited less than a minute

Comment: Happy it got solved!